# pyenv mkvirtualenv is unable to work with pypy3

Tags: python, virtualenv, pypy, virtualenvwrapper, pyenv

I've set up pyenv with pyenv-virtualenv and pyenv-virtualenvwrapper using brew on Mac Catalina. I installed the most recent pypy with:

`pyenv install pypy3.6-7.3.0`

which worked. I upgraded its pip to resolve another error with

`pip3 install --upgrade pip`

which fixed it not being able to find pip. I'm now trying to run:

`mkvirtualenv test_env -v -p pypy3.6-7.3.0`

where I get the error:

```
find interpreter for spec PythonSpec(path=/Users/alesi/.virtualenvs/pypy3.6-7.3.0)
proposed PythonInfo(spec=PyPy3.6.9.final.0-64, exe=/Users/alesi/.pyenv/versions/pypy3.6-7.3.0/bin/python, platform=darwin, version='3.6.9 (1608da62bfc7, Dec 23 2019, 10:50:17)\n[PyPy 7.3.0 with GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)]', encoding_fs_io=utf-8-UTF-8)
proposed PathPythonInfo(spec=CPython2.7.16.final.0-64, system=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python, exe=/usr/bin/python, platform=darwin, version='2.7.16 (default, Dec 13 2019, 18:00:32) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.32.4) (-macos10.15-objc-s', encoding_fs_io=utf-8-None)
RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='pypy3.6-7.3.0'
```

Why can't I get this env built?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+PythonInfo

Comment: ^ Does not solve my issue.

Comment: `virtualenv` should be downgraded for the same Python that used by `mkvirtualenv`. Or better for all Pythons you have installed.

Comment: Downgrading didn't work but running:
pyenv shell pypy3.6-7.3.0
mkvirtualenv test_env
creates the environment fine. Do you know why I can't explicitly state the environment in one command?